# Which CRM systems work well with Redmine?

Tags: pm-software, redmine

I am using Redmine for managing a small team of developers. To organize our contacts, we need a CRM system soon. Are there any CRM systems that have a Redmine integration? Is it possible to link Redmine-tickets to contacts or phone-minutes?

Comment: maybe salesforce.com will help you?

Comment: I would like to work with a self-hosted open-source solution.

Answer (score 5):

Although it's a third-party development, there is a bridge to [SugarCRM](http://tekdi.net/Blogs/CRM/SugarCRM-redmine-integration.html), which is self-hosted FOSS.

I haven't tried it yet, but plan to.

Answer (score 2):

You could use my CRM plugin (Contacts plugin) for redmine (http://www.redminecrm.com)

- Managing contacts relations (CRM)
- Native redmine interface
- Tagging and mutlitag filtering
- Managing deals workflow and controlling sales funnel
- Resolve duplicates
- Contacts avatars (include gravatar.org service)
- Contacts task management (integration with issues)
- Contacts across projects
- Support for MySQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL

Comment: Hi Kirill. Can you please tell me if sugarCRM has some important features which redmineCRM does not have? I did not work with any of these that's why I need an expert's answer

Answer (score 0):

1. obsolete (?): [Customer Plugin](https://github.com/edavis10/redmine-customer-plugin/)`https://github.com/edavis10/redmine-customer-plugin/`
2. Ruby-based CRM, don't know about Redmine integration: [Rails CRM (needs mongoDB)](https://github.com/brobertsaz/railscrm) `https://github.com/brobertsaz/railscrm`

Comment: Please expand your answer by adding more details from the referenced links. Pay special attention how it answers the  original question, e.g. how the software integrates with Redmine.